# Nginx image in Docker reflects bind but does not show correct content

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I'm using docker toolbox in my Win 7 desktop, I'm creating a container from nginx using the following command:

```
docker container run -p 8082:80 -v //c/Users/TestDocker/:/usr/share/nginx/ -d --rm nginx
```

The content in the container reflects what it is in my host folder:

[image]

In the container:

[image]

But the actual page display is this:

[image]

Obviously the same locally:

[image]

Nginx configuration file points to the same location as the bind is:

[image]

Any cloud on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Open a new incognito window and try in that

Comment: Already done, it is not because cache

Comment: Kill the container and run it using `docker container run -p 8082:80 -v //c/Users/TestDocker/:/usr/share/nginx/ -it --rm nginx` so you can see what is happening when you hit the request

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @TarunLalwani, I did it an the common output rises up:
    192.168.99.1 - - [28/Aug/2017:21:20:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"

What it is really interesting is other files in the bind are displayed correctly but index.html not

Comment: The VM in VirtualBox which is used by ToolBox, Go to Settings of it and Shared Folders Tab. Post the image of that in your question

Answer (score 1):

This is not worthy of an answer but I don't have the reputation to comment:

Your docker command maps `8082:80` but you're using port `8083` in the browser.
Is there a chance you're interacting with the wrong container?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I tried several containers with the same bind I just posted the wrong image, but the problem is still the same